# Have you got a worked example of using Postgres through ODBC with openssl and the Progress DataDirect Linux driver?

Tags: linux, postgresql, openssl, odbc

I am new to openssl configuration, Postgres, and the Progress DataDirect ODBC driver, and I am trying to set this up. I have Postgres working in a container, set up with

```
tjcw:~$ openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key fd.key -out fd.crt
Enter pass phrase for fd.key:
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [XX]:
State or Province Name (full name) []:
Locality Name (eg, city) [Default City]:
Organization Name (eg, company) [Default Company Ltd]:
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:
Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) []:
Email Address []:
tjcw:~$ openssl rsa -in fd.key -out fd.plain.key
Enter pass phrase for fd.key:
writing RSA key
tjcw:~$
```

and this in my Dockerfile

```
FROM docker.io/postgres
COPY init-user-db.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-user-db.sh
RUN mkdir /var/lib/postgresql/ssl
RUN chown postgres.postgres /var/lib/postgresql/ssl
COPY fd.crt /var/lib/postgresql/ssl/server.crt
COPY fd.plain.key /var/lib/postgresql/ssl/server.key
RUN chown postgres.postgres /var/lib/postgresql/ssl/server.crt /var/lib/postgresql/ssl/server.key
RUN chmod 400 /var/lib/postgresql/ssl/server.crt /var/lib/postgresql/ssl/server.key
RUN ls -ld /var/ /var/lib/ /var/lib/postgresql/ /var/lib/postgresql/ssl/
RUN sed -i 's/#ssl = off/ssl = on/' /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample
RUN sed -i 's/#ssl/ssl/' /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample
RUN sed -i 's-server.crt-/var/lib/postgresql/ssl/server.crt-' /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample
RUN sed -i 's-server.key-/var/lib/postgresql/ssl/server.key-' /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample
```

`podman logs` shows the server starting as expected.

But I don't know how to configure the client. This is what I had in `/etc/odbcinst.ini` to run without encryption

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
PostgreSQL=DataDirect 8.0 PostgreSQL

# Driver from the postgresql-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[PostgreSQL]
Description     = ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver          = /home/tjcw/ODBC/drivers/lib/UKpsql95.so
HostName=localhost
PortNumber=5432
Database=acedb
```

The Progress DataDirect documentation is here https://docs.progress.com/bundle/datadirect-postgresql-odbc-80/page/Certificate-based-authentication_2.html but it's not clear to me what I need to do on the client side to get this to work.

Please can someone give me an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

I put the following in ~/odbc.ini

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
POSTGRES=DataDirect ODBC Postgres Wire Protocol

;# POSTGRES stanza

[ACEDB]
DRIVER=/home/tjcw/ODBC/drivers/lib/UKpsql95.so
Description=IBM Postgres ODBC Database
Database=acedb
HostName=localhost
PortNumber=5432
;PortNumber=33679
EncryptionMethod=1
HostName=localhost
HostNameInCertificate=localhost
ValidateServerCertificate=0
```

and ran an SQL request.

```
tjcw:src$ sudo tcpdump -i lo -w tcpdump.log 'tcp port 5432'
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C31 packets captured
62 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
tjcw:src$ wireshark
```

gave me the following picture
[image: Wireshark picture of encrypted session]